# How to lock a file, read content and overwrite (truncate) it

Tags: php, file

When I use option `w+` it truncates the file before reading it. I want to lock the file which is used by multiple scripts, then read and overwrite, then unlock. This is the simplified code.

```
$fp = fopen($file, "w+");
if(flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    $content = fread($fp, $filesize);
    echo $content; // this is empty, must not be empty
    $job_queue = explode("\n", $content, LOCK_EX);
    $next_job = array_shift($job_queue);
    fwrite($fp, implode("\n", $job_queue));
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    echo '<br>Error: cannot lock job queue file';
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, added manually a truncate to 0 (beginning of file) and changed open option to `a+`

```
$fp = fopen($file, "a+");
if(flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    $content = fread($fp, $filesize);
    echo $content; // this is not empty now
    $job_queue = explode("\n", $content, LOCK_EX);
    $next_job = array_shift($job_queue);
    ftruncate($fp, 0);
    fwrite($fp, implode("\n", $job_queue));
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    echo '<br>Error: cannot lock job queue file';
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = read mode only
r+ = read/write mode
w = write mode only
w+ = read/write mode, if the file already exists override it (empty it)
```

do "r+" instead and truncate with PHP's [`ftruncate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php)

Comment: I just did this but you beat me to the answer :D

Comment: so it works, right?

Comment: No. It does not work with r+. Need to do a+ and truncate to 0

Comment: look at example #1 in the docs, it uses, `r+`

Comment: It corrupts the file, I am not understanding why.

Comment: maybe you need to `rewind()` ?

Comment: Yeah, that seems an OK example. I will stop commenting here, cos SO is complaining :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238007/discussion-between-flaxon-and-jack).